# Installing PyQt5 on Raspberry (Buster) with Python 3.7.3

Tags: python-3.x, pip, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, sip

I already spent an hour or so googling everywhere. I tried many things like [Install pyqt5 5.14.1 on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711301/install-pyqt5-5-14-1-on-linux) (or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780302/pip3-install-pyqt5-user-fails) or [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiC1v-YoLboAhWiunEKHfVKC6YQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F56418874%2Fcant-install-pyqt5-using-pip&usg=AOvVaw2ngccg5U6B66eYurilQdbq)).

I created a fresh buster image, which comes with Python3.7.3 and tried different options, but none of them works:

```
pip3 install pyqt5

Preparing wheel metadata ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpv7ke9s7c
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-98dyo0xi/pyqt5
Complete output (31 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 103, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 257, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 240, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 108, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    config_settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 136, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
    whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
    project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 387, in setup
    self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
  File "project.py", line 62, in apply_user_defaults
    super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-yyus0ja8/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 86, in apply_user_defaults
    super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 202, in apply_user_defaults
    self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-yyus0ja8/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
    "specify a working qmake or add it to PATH")
sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpv7ke9s7c Check the logs for full command output.
```

or:

```
pip3 install pyqt5==5.14.0

ERROR: pyqt5==5.14.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/5b/e760ec4f868cb77cee45b4554bf15d3fe6972176e89c4e3faac941213694/PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=0145a6b7de15756366decb736c349a0cb510d706c83fda5b8cd9e0557bc1da72 has a pyproject.toml file that does not comply with PEP 518: 'build-system.requires' contains an invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'
```

I also tried:
    python3 -m pip install pyqt5

I woult like to "just install it" not with a virt env or something. Also because of missing knowledge I want to avoid building it from source.

I also updated pip to 20.0.2 already.

Comment: execute `sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then `sudo python3 -m pip install pyqt5`

Comment: Been there, done that: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (20.0.2)`

Comment: or execute: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`

Comment: I can execute this, I do not get any error, but still `import pyqt5` fails (it also does not show up under my list of installed modules.

Comment: Your import is incorrect, you must use: `from PyQt5 import QtCore` `print(QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)`

Comment: that works. Why is the package not visible under my list of modules: `import pkg_resources; installed_packages = [(d.project_name, d.version) for d in pkg_resources.working_set]`